# Are on_idle hooks transactional?

Tags: runtime, transactions, hook

Trying to call a function marked as `#[require_transactional]` from on_idle() hook triggers the error `Err : Transactional(NoLayer)`.

I realise the transactional macro is optional for extrinsics and the default behaviour of all extrinsics is transactional after [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11927). But I'm curious if its safe to execute transactional calls from pallet hooks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, pallet hooks are not transactional by default, only extrinsics are.

You should be able to create a transactional layer within the pallet hook so that the error of `NoLayer` goes away, but generally, you should keep logic within your hooks to be infalliable.

If you choose to use a transactional layer, something as simple as this should work:

```
fn on_idle(_block: T::BlockNumber, remaining_weight: Weight) -> Weight {
    with_transaction(|| {
        // your transactional function here
    })
}
```